# How can we inherit the value of one table into another using hash table in c#

Tags: c#, .net

How can we inherit the values of table from one to another  using hash table in C#

Comment: What are you even asking about? Do you mean "How can we copy the values from one Map/Dictionary/Table data structure to another, using the Hashtable class?" or "How can we copy the contents of one database table to another, while utilizing the Hashtable data structure?"

Comment: You know, the big rich textbox is where you should add your question body (i.e. add details, your code, etc), it's not an other 'title' field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "*inherit the values of table from one to another*" you mean add the values from one Hashtable to another, you can either use the Hashtable constructor [`Hashtable(IDictionary)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/kdkta2sx(v=vs.110).aspx) which copies the elements to the new Hashtable:

```
// Hashtable oldTable
Hashtable newTable = new Hashtable(oldTable);
```

or if you have an existing Hashtable, you can do:

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in tableA)
{
    tableB[entry.Key] = entry.Value;
}
```